# Как написать чат - бота для telegram на с++?

Tags: c++

Я учу с++ и хочу создать своего чат-бота для telegram на с++!
Посоветуйте пожалуйста какой нибудь материал на эту тему.
P.S. Кроме Telegram API=)

Comment: Я могу еще только google посоветовать. Потому что книг на эту тему нет.

Comment: если я правильно понял документацию, телеграм использует http, поэтому, для начала нужно найти подходящий http клиент, curl или что то подобное

Comment: Боты бывают очень разные, и создаются для разных целей. В такой общей постановке, могу посоветовать только https://dev.botframework.com/ , правда там примеры только на C# и JS, но из C++ его тоже можно использовать через CLI..

Comment: Я писал бота для telegram, но не до конца. Были проблемы разного рода, в том числе и то, что русский текст присылался в utf кодировке \u4509, и так далее. Я делал на си, там вроде бы api были написаны и два способа, с помощью poll и ещё какой то.